# What graphic can be used to represent a maintenance category?

Tags: website-design, symbolism

On my site I have some categories. One of which is "Website Maintenance". I want to create a graphic (about 300x by 250y) that represents the Website Maintenance category. But I'm at a low right now, and can't think of anything.

Can someone please help? Offer some suggestions? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

A spanner (for my US readers - a wrench) is usually associated with maintentance (tighening bolts and whatnot) perhaps you could cross this imagery with something computer or website related. Crossing the both images will give your user an immediate idea of what the icon represents.

Could you perhaps post an image of one of your other icons, we may be able to make suggestions that adhere to your styling as well.

Answer (score 5):

- A gear
- Tools: hammer, screwdriver

Comment: I like the Gear! Suggests behind the scenes modification. Adjusting and improving the backend definitely comes under the website maintenance category.

Answer (score 3):

A pictogram of a mouse+cord crossing a mop?

Answer (score 0):

I've always liked the frowny-face mac:

[image: frowny-face mac]

Maybe something like that? Chrome uses something similar for when a page stops responding.

Comment: I think this would give me the impression that something is broken. Website maintenance maybe updating content, swapping out images etc.

Comment: True...the wrench (spanner) that Daniel recommended seems to be the most common icon.

Answer (score -1):

What about the road sign of work in progress - even older people can associate it with "something being done right now - all may not work":

[image]
(image from http://frontierpsychiatrist.co.uk)